# RangeError Node.JS

Tags: node.js, error-handling

**Hi everyone! Beginner here!**

I have made a little Node.JS app with Socket.IO which worked perfectly until I decided to put my socket code in an object to allow namespace management. I'm now having an issue with this method (I believe.)

Its aim is to ask all clients to send their ids every 30 seconds. Unfortunately the console sends me an error:

> "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at Function.isBuffer (buffer.js:225:23)"

I still haven't found where my error was and would appreciate your help very much!

*The method:*

```
this.chckConnected = function(){
    this.connectedIds = [];
    this.connected = 0;
    io.of('/' + name).emit("askId");
    setTimeout(function(){
    io.of('/' + name).emit("nbCo", this.connected);}, 1000);
    setTimeout(this.chckConnected, 30000);
};
setTimeout(this.chckConnected, 1000);
```

*The socket handler:*

```
     socket.on("sendId", function(sendId){ //Check if people are online
        if(connectedIds.indexOf(sendId) == -1){
            connectedIds.push(sendId);
            connected++;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an infinite loop in chckConnected function, even if there's a timeout.

```
this.chckConnected = function(){
  this.connectedIds = [];
  this.connected = 0;
  io.of('/' + name).emit("askId");
  setTimeout(function(){
  io.of('/' + name).emit("nbCo", this.connected);}, 1000);
  //setTimeout(this.chckConnected, 30000); // remove this line
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was abvious! I feel stupid!